# Does adding self-referential foreign key increase performance for recursive queries in hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I am trying to do some operations on a tree structure stored in a relational database.

For example lets say some hierarchical structure of an organisation is modeled as

1. ID - unique employee id
2. PID - ID immediate manager of employee

**Create table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE org (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  pid INT REFERENCES org(id),
  value INT
);
```

**sample query for above table:** we need to calculate number of employees directly or indirectly under a manager

- Also does this added constraint help in recursive CTE expressions (improve performance for sample query?
- Or not adding any self-referential constraints, but adding adding index on ID field, would that improve the sample query lookup

Comment: The constraint itself cannot improve because the constraint is a rule and it does not change the structure. Adding the index by `id` makes no sense because this index (as primary key) already exists. But you may create an index by `(pid)` or by `(pid, id)` - in theory this may improve (must be tested in practice).

Comment: I don't see the SQL for the sample query.

Comment: Unless you have thousands of rows in the table, the performance issues will be minimal.